# Disable Network Level Security on my Azure Virtual machine remotely

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-nsg, azure-vm

Whenever I try to login in my Server I get following error
The remote computer that you are trying to connect to requires Network Level Authentication (NLA), but your Windows domain controller cannot be contacted to perform NLA. If you are an administrator on the remote computer, you can disable NLA by using the options on the Remote tab of the System Properties dialog box.

I cant connect to my server remotely using powershell and Remote registry(regedit) inspite of enabling TCP port 5986. Can any one suggest a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an easy method to disable NLA via the Azure portal. You can navigate the Operation---Run command---select the **DisableNLA** script, then click **Run** button after finishing the run command script, restart your Azure VM for the change to take effect.

[image]

**Alternatively**, you also could invoke run command with PowerShell or Azure CLI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command

**For example**

Run these PowerShell scripts to disable or enable the NLA of the remote computer on the local machine with `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName '<myResourceGroup>' -Name '<myVMName>' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath '<pathToScript>' -Parameter @{"arg1" = "var1";"arg2" = "var2"}`

```
$ComputerName = "remote computer"

# Getting the NLA information
(Get-WmiObject -class "Win32_TSGeneralSetting" -Namespace root\cimv2\terminalservices -ComputerName $ComputerName -Filter "TerminalName='RDP-tcp'").UserAuthenticationRequired

# Setting the NLA information to Disabled
(Get-WmiObject -class "Win32_TSGeneralSetting" -Namespace root\cimv2\terminalservices -ComputerName $ComputerName -Filter "TerminalName='RDP-tcp'").SetUserAuthenticationRequired(0)

# Setting the NLA information to Enabled
(Get-WmiObject -class "Win32_TSGeneralSetting" -Namespace root\cimv2\terminalservices -ComputerName $ComputerName -Filter "TerminalName='RDP-tcp'").SetUserAuthenticationRequired(1)


# -Parameter @{"arg1" = "var1";"arg2" = "var2"}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Hello, Actually I have created the VM using custom Image so cant find the Run command Option there.. could you provide a workaround for that. Also, Wmi object PS command is not working for me I get something as RPC is unavailable. Please suggest a workaround

Comment: Do you [create a managed image from that Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource)? If so, you can create a new Azure VM from that managed image, see [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-generalized-managed). The new Azure VM also keep the data from the original the OS and data disks.